# How to detect 401 error when loading video src?

Tags: javascript, html5-video

I currently use following, but `event` reveals little about error.

```js
const video = document.getElementById("video")
const source = video.getAttribute("data-source")
video.src = source;
video.addEventListener("error", (event) => {
    console.log("BOOM")
})
```

Comment: It's an ugly solution but you could check inside the error with a separate fetch (perhaps using a HEAD req) to that endpoint and check the response, would that solve your issue?

Comment: Thanks for helping out @tbjgolden. Great fallback idea!

Answer (score 1):

> *"...But `event` reveals little about error."*

Well you did put `console.log("BOOM")` as the response. It was never gonna be informative.

You want to detect Error type of either: `MEDIA_ERR_NETWORK` or `MEDIA_ERR_SRC_NOT_SUPPORTED`.

Try something like this:

```
video.addEventListener("error", (event) => { handle_Media_Errors (event) } );

function handle_Media_Errors (evt) 
{
    //# code credits: https://gist.github.com/wilmoore/3252894
    //# video playback failed - show a message saying why...
    switch (evt.target.error.code) 
    {
        case evt.target.error.MEDIA_ERR_DECODE:
        console.log('Media Error ::: The video could not be decoded.');
        break;
        
        case evt.target.error.MEDIA_ERR_ABORTED:
        console.log('Media Error ::: video playback was aborted.');
        break;
        
        case evt.target.error.MEDIA_ERR_SRC_NOT_SUPPORTED:
        console.log('Media Error ::: The video could not be loaded or its format is not supported.');
        break;
            
        case evt.target.error.MEDIA_ERR_NETWORK:
        console.log('Media Error ::: Video download failed due to a network error');
        break;
        
        default:
        console.log('Media Error ::: An unknown error with your media file has occurred.');
        break;
    }
    
    
}
```