# HTML5 video cannot be played on mobile browsers

Tags: javascript, mobile, html5-video

I have some videos (H.264) cannot be played on mobile browsers but can be played on desktop browsers. I use the same browsers (Chrome, Safari) on both desktop and mobiles. However the video control on mobile browser is blank and seems like the video is not loaded correctly.

I am really confused about this issue, and the code I use is really simple:

`<video controls style="width:100%"><source src="" type="video/mp4"></video>`

Comment: Your `src` is empty?

Comment: You don't have a question though... Please show a demo of the problem in action. Are you sure your MP4 contains H264? Try adding an [event listener for HTML5 errors](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71711283/2057709).